# Kendo: Extend ObservableObject with new properties

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have a kendo DataSource object from which I get an object. I would like to extend this object before binding it to a Kendo widget to provide additional fields.

```
var studentId = 4711
var student = studentDataSource.get(studentId);

kendo.bind($("#student-view"), student, kendo.mobile.ui);
```

E.g. `student` then looks like this:

```
{
    FirstName: "Peter",
    LastName: "Pan"
}
```

Somehow I would like to extend it to have it like this:

```
{
    FistName: "Peter",
    LastName: "Pan",
    DisplayName: function() {
        return this.get("LastName") + ", " + this.get("FirstName");
    }
}
```

Is this somehow possible or do I have to write every field of the object I retrieve from the datasource one by one into a new viewModel which I later on bind to the view?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thank you Lars for that hint! Seems to be working with the datasource schema definition! Obviously I didn't use the correct key words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by using the kendo datasource schema definition:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema: {
        model: {
            DisplayName: function() {
                return this.get("LastName") + ", " + this.get("FirstName");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks to Lars Höppner for the hint!